# How do I increase my number count by 1 in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello im new to javascript. My function is suppose to increase my count by 1 every-time i call it but when i run it in console it just repeats 1. Any suggestions?

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function bizzBuzz(){
   output.push(count);
   count++;
   console.log(output);
}

bizzBuzz();
```

Comment: Did you call `bizzBuzz` more than once?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count = 0;
var output = [];

function bizzBuzz() {
  output.push(count += 1);
  console.log(output);
}

bizzBuzz();
bizzBuzz();
```